# a problem while installing Brackets

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-sources

i used this commands to install brackets

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

but i had this problem

```
    Unpacking brackets (1.9.0libgcrypt11-17312+1~webupd8~0) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libxxf86vm1:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libxxf86vm1; however:
  Package libxxf86vm1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglu1-mesa:i386:
 libglu1-mesa:i386 depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglu1-mesa:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine-stable-i386:i386:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa | libglu1; however:
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 is not configured yet.
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 which provides libglu1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine-stable-i386:i386 (--configure):
 depenNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine-stable:
 wine-stable depends on wine-stable-i386 (= 2.0.1~xenial); however:
  Package wine-stable-i386:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine-stable (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-i386:i386:
 wine1.6-i386:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa | libglu1; however:
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 is not configured yet.
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 which provides libglu1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-i386:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwine-development:i386:
 libwine-development:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa | libglu1; however:
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 is not configured yet.
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 which provides libglu1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwinNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                   e-development:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine32-development:i386:
 wine32-development:i386 depends on libwine-development (= 1.9.6-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libwine-development:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine32-development:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up brackets (1.9.0libgcrypt11-17312+1~webupd8~0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6:
 wine1.6 depends on wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14); however:
  Package wine1.6-i386:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-amd64:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               wine1.6-amd64 depends on wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14); however:
  Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxxf86vm1:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 libglu1-mesa:i386
 wine-stable-i386:i386
 wine-stable
 wine1.6-i386:i386
 libwine-development:i386
 wine32-development:i386
 wine1.6
 wine1.6-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main error and causes the others because of dependency:
`dpkg: error processing package libxxf86vm1:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration`

Commands to try:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxxf86vm1:i386`
`sudo apt-get purge libxxf86vm1:i386` then `sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm1:i386`
`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite libxxf86vm1:i386`

Comment: thanks but there is a problem with the last command 
===
ahmed@Anonymous:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite libxxf86vm1:i386
dpkg: error processing archive libxxf86vm1:i386 (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxxf86vm1:i386
===
and wine was removed !

Comment: so it's not there  one of the others worked??

Comment: they all worked 
haven't i to write them all ?
and can i reinstall wine without problem

Comment: only need to get one to work, try to reinstall wine